# How to store a value in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to store the DirectorID value returned by this statement, to use it in a query in another table (filmTable):

```
select DirectorID 
from dbo.tblDirector 
where DirectorName='Steven Spielberg'
```

I want to store it in an int variable,
I know I should declare a variable but I don't know how?

Comment: @MohammedElshawaf Yes, variables/procedural extensions aren't standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For SQL Sever:

```
declare @directorId int

select @directorId = DirectorID 
from dbo.tblDirector 
where DirectorName='Steven Spielberg'
```

Comment: when I run this statement,
select FilmName from dbo.tblFilm where FilmDirectorID=@directorId;

an error says: Must declare the scalar variable "@directorId".
??

Comment: @MohammedElshawaf May be you need just join those tables without using any temporary variables by: SELECT FilmName FROM tblFilm INNER JOIN tblDirector ON tblFilm.FilmDirectorID = tblDirector.DirectorID

Comment: Execuse me: how to query a specific DirectorID it that case?, say DirectorID=4

Comment: @MohammedElshawaf By adding where clause: SELECT FilmName FROM tblFilm INNER JOIN tblDirector ON tblFilm.FilmDirectorID = tblDirector.DirectorID WHERE  tblDirector.DirectorID = 4